# Same focal distance, narrow FOV but bigger sensor. How is possible?

Tags: focal-length, sensor, iphone

The iPhone 7 Plus, according to the exif, has 4 mm focal distance 28 mm equivalent.
The iPhone 8 Plus, according to the exif, has 3.99 mm focal distance 29 mm equivalent.

The iPhone 8's field of view is narrower than the iPhone 7's FOV and the logic tell me that the sensor should be a little smaller. But, according to Apple, iPhone 8 has a larger sensor. The lens is the same, how is possible?

Comment: Just some _more creative rounding_ of the numbers. ;)

Comment: "think different!" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The 29 mm equivalent means it is a smaller sensor (very slightly).

I am assuming your numbers are correct (I don't know myself, nor about what Apple says.)  Possibly there are a coupe of iPhone 8 sensor options?

But just looking at your numbers:

4 mm FL / 28 mm equivalent is 28/4 = 7x crop factor.

3.99 mm FL / 29 mm equivalent is 29/3.99 = 7.27x crop factor.

It means a 35 mm film frame is 7 or 7.27 times larger, so 7.27 is a bit smaller than 7, maybe 4%.

The crop factor of the larger 35 mm film frame is 1x.

Technically, 7x crop computes a 4:3 sensor size of Width 4.94 mm, Height 3.71 mm,, and at 4mm FL, a field of view of 63.4 x 49.7  degrees.

And 7.27x crop computes sensor size ofWidth 4.76 mm, Height 3.57 mm, and at 3.99 mm FL, a field of view of 61.6 x 48.2 degrees.

Not much difference.